# Setting up Jenkins job in Rundeck 3.4.9 community version

Tags: jenkins, rundeck

I want to setup a Jenkins job which should be triggered by Rundeck. I have already installed Rundeck plugin and tested the connection between Rundeck and Jenkins which is working as expected.
Now, my requirement is that the same Jenkins job should be triggered by Rundeck. I am using Rundeck 3.4.9 community version.

How can I setup a Jenkins job in Rundeck and what configurations I need to do on both Rundeck and Jenkins end?

Answer (score 1):

You can design a Rundeck job that call the Jenkins job using this endpoint via [CURL](https://serverfault.com/a/888248).

I tested successfully with this endpoint:

`http://user:JENKINS_USER_TOKEN@localhost:8080/job/TestJob/build`

You can use the [http workflow step](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/http-step) to send post requests using that URL format.

[Source](https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/dkyybiyuUBc/m/x53UFzSOBAAJ).

Here is a job definition example:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 1fa2923a-5b1d-4ea2-97d1-4cc2a3726f07
  loglevel: INFO
  name: ExampleJENKINS
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: echo "starting..."
    - fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: curl -vvv -X POST http://admin:11bd72f1f22653cf7158c7961f60476a1d@localhost:8080/job/MyJenkinsJob/build
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 1fa2923a-5b1d-4ea2-97d1-4cc2a3726f07
```

Another way is to use the [HTTP Step plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/http-step) with a basic authentication configured.

The job definition example:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 1fa2923a-5b1d-4ea2-97d1-4cc2a3726f07
  loglevel: INFO
  name: ExampleJENKINS
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: echo "starting..."
    - configuration:
        authentication: Basic
        checkResponseCode: 'false'
        method: POST
        password: keys/jenkins_admin_token
        printResponse: 'false'
        printResponseToFile: 'false'
        proxySettings: 'false'
        remoteUrl: http://localhost:8080/job/MyJenkinsJob/build
        sslVerify: 'true'
        timeout: '30000'
        username: admin
      nodeStep: true
      type: edu.ohio.ais.rundeck.HttpWorkflowNodeStepPlugin
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 1fa2923a-5b1d-4ea2-97d1-4cc2a3726f07
```